# Questions about the maximal irreducible components of a space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with an identity, $X$ denotes its prime spectrum, that is, $X=spec(A)$, then there is a conclusion says that the maximal irreducible components of $X$ are the closed sets $V(p)$  *[$V(E)$ denotes the set of all prime ideals of $A$ which contains $E$]*, where $p$ is a minimal prime ideal of $A$. It is quite easy to show that $V(p)$ is an irreducible component of $X$ if $p$ is a minimal prime of $A$. But I don't know how to prove that $V(p)$ is a maximal component. I can do the part that when M is a finite union of all $V(p)$, M is not an irreducible component. What about the infinite union of $V(p)$?

Comment: An infinite union of the $V(p)$ wouldn't be irreducible.

Comment: Yeah,but I have no ideal about the infinite one

Comment: I don't get the question. Components are maximal by definition. There is an antitone bijection between prime ideals and irreducible closed sets. Hence, there is a bijection between minimal prime ideals and maximal irreducible closed sets, i.e. irreducible components.

Comment: Maybe my statement is a little ambigous. I am interested in the bijection between prime ideals and irreducible closed sets as you mentioned. If I let $f$ denote the map which sends a prime ideal $p$ to $V(p)$, then $f$ is an injection, but how to show $f$ is a surjection?

Comment: This is standard, can be found in every introduction to algebraic geometry. But it is also a good exercise. A closed set has the form $V(a)$ for some ideal $a \subseteq A$. Assuming it is irreducible, show that $a$ is prime. Try to prove it.

Comment: I will have a try, Thank you so much